# is it possible to extract a cookie from a share intent on android?

Tags: android, html, android-intent, cookies, jsoup

**is it possible to extract a cookie from a share intent on android?**

I am not able to find any information on this.

I am trying to parse the HTML of website using JSOUP after the user presses the share button. The problem is that the connection i create with JSOUP does not know anything about the cookie and hence asks for confirmation to accept the cookies.

Because of this, the HTML that gets parsed is only the HTML of the little window popup of the website that asks you to accept the cookie. I am not able to connect to the real website directly.

So i thought maybe extracting the cookie from the share intent would do. I wouldnt know how to do this otherwise as I have been trying quite alot already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to extract a cookie from a share intent on android?

No.

> I am not able to find any information on this.

That is because an `Intent` does not have cookies, any more than an `Integer` does.

Comment: Thanks,, i am gonna have to find another way to solve this cookie problem then,, would you happen to have a suggestion?

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything: Not really. If the user shares a URL that requires authentication, there is nothing much that you can do other than have the user re-authenticate (e.g., use a `WebView`). In this case, you are no different than another Web browser, and you would not expect Chrome to share cookies with Firefox, for example.

Comment: Hmm i see,, thanks again! I do wonder though how a website thumbnail generator service for example is able to capture the image of the website without the cookie pop up window. http://tweakers.net for example, which is a dutch tech news website. It has no authentication or anything, just a simple "accept use of cookies" window. When I try to capture it, the pop-up window is in front of it but when I tried with some other online thumbnail generator, they seem to be able to accept it and capture the image of the real domain